# How to place arrow icons above & below input field?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and i've created a row with three columns, but for the love of me i can't properly align the icons above the input fields, like the screenshot below the code.
The icons behave like block elements and are placed next to the input fields, rather then above.

Here's an image of what i've achieved so far:

[image]

Can someone help me out, or atleast point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="4">       
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_up</v-icon>
      <input type="text" />
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_down</v-icon>
      <span>:</span>
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_up</v-icon>
      <input type="text" />
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_down</v-icon>
    </v-col>
<v-row>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you share an image of your inspector on the problematic divs please ?

Comment: @JérômeW Done, if i understood you correctly.

Comment: It helps but it's not what I asked. On your browser dev tools you can launch the inspector with elements and related css ^^ @Y.Futekov for example if you're using Google chrome => https://www.templatemonster.com/help/use-google-chrome-web-inspector.html

Comment: @JérômeW Done, i think.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad your found the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align this using flex classes.

```
<v-col cols="4">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-center">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_up</v-icon>
      <input type="text" />
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_down</v-icon>
    </div>
    <span class="mx-2">:</span>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_up</v-icon>
      <input type="text" />
      <v-icon>arrow_drop_down</v-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-col>
```

I have added below css to size input boxes.

```
input{
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  border: solid thin blue
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just place those elements like

```
v-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;  //or bottom, left, right ro align
}
```

?